# How to set up wireshark to view certain ports?

Tags: linux, wireshark

As part of a homework I am meant to be doing the following, but I have been off from school for personal reasons. Could someone help with how I am meant to go about doing this?

1. "Set up Wireshark to view Src Host, Src Destination & Src Port."
2. "Use the wireshark_setup.pcapng file located in the Files directory."

How would I go about completing this? I sound stupid asking but I honestly do not have any idea.

After completing those tasks we are given the questions:

1. "Using wireshark_setup.pcapng, filter the packets to view only HTTP requests. What is the source IP address shown on the last packet?"
2. "Within that same packet, what is the time shown? Your answer must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format adjusted for UTC."
3. "What is the destination IP address of the last packet?"

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1):

In the Wireshark menu, go to `View` > `Time Display Format` and select `UTC Date and Time of Day`. Use `http.request` filter for filtering only HTTP traffic, sort by the number `No.` to view the last packet.

[image]